# Prove that all the solutions of (2): $\frac{dy}{dt}=A(t)y+f(t)$ are bounded in $ \left[t_0,+\infty \right )$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, trace

I have a problem:

> Assume that system (1): $$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=A(t)x$$ is stable, where
>   $A(t) \in C\left [t_0,+\infty  \right )$, when $t \to \infty$
>
> and $$\begin{cases}
>  & \mathrm{  } \lim \inf_{t \to \infty}\int_{t_0}^{t}Tr(A(t_1)dt_1> - \infty;(1') \\ \\
>  & \mathrm{  } \int_{t_0}^{\infty}\left \|f(t_1)  \right \|dt_1<+\infty; (2').
> \end{cases}$$
>
> Prove that all the solutions of (2): $$\frac{dy}{dt}=A(t)y+f(t)$$ are
>   bounded in $ \left[t_0,+\infty  \right )$.

...........................................................................

Ok, Here's my solution: (I'm not sure, but I still post it).

- Assume that $X(t)$ be a fundamental matrix of (1), $X(t_0)=E$. Then $$y(t)=X(t)X^{-1}(t)x(t_0)+X(t)\int_{t_0}^{t}X^{-1}(s)f(s)\mathrm{ds}$$
- Because system (1) is stable, so $X(t)$ is bounded
- Applying Ostrogradski - Liouville, we have:$$\det X(t)=\det E \cdot \exp \left[\int_{t_0}^{t} TrA(s)\mathrm{ds}\right]=\exp \left[\int_{t_0}^{t} TrA(s)\mathrm{ds}\right]$$
  whence 
  $$\lim \inf_{t \to \infty}\int_{t_0}^{t}Tr(A(s)\mathrm{d}s=\lim \inf_{t \to \infty}\ln\det X(t)> - \infty$$ We see that, provided (1') is satisfied, $X^{-1}(t)$ is bounded as $t \to \infty$.
- Let $c_1=\max\{\sup_{t \ge t_0}\|X(t)\|;\sup_{t \ge t_0}\|X^{-1}(t)\|;\sup\|y(t_0)\|\}$.

Therefore, $\|y(t)\| \le c_{1}^{3}+c_{1}^{2}\int_{t_0}^{t}\|f(s)\|\mathrm{d}s$.

Since (2'): $\int_{t_0}^{\infty}\left \|f(t_1)  \right \|dt_1<+\infty$, we're done!

I've made several errors with my solution, may be! :(.
Anyone can check it help me? Thanks!

Comment: Just a notational comment: this would be a lot clearer if you indicated that $x$ and $y$ were vectors, or at least mentioned $y\in \mathbb R^n$ somewhere.